# How can I convert a Class Component which extends another Class component in a Functional Component in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

How can I convert a Class Component which extends another Class component in a Functional Component in ReactJS?

input.jsx [Functional Component]

```
const Input = ({ name, label, error, ...rest }) => {
    return (
        <div className="mb-3">
            <label htmlFor={name} className="form-label">
                {label}
            </label>
            <input
                autoFocus
                {...rest}
                id={name}
                name={name}
                className="form-control"
            />
            {error && <div className="alert alert-danger">{error}</div>}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Input
```

form.jsx [Class Component]

```
import React, { Component } from "react"
import Input from "./input"
import Joi from "joi"

class Form extends Component {
    state = {
        data: {},
        errors: {}
    }

    validate = () => {
        const options = { abortEarly: false }
        const schemaJoi = Joi.object(this.schema)
        const { error } = schemaJoi.validate(this.state.data, options)
        if (!error) return null

        const errors = {}
        error.details.map(item => (errors[item.path[0]] = item.message))
        return errors
    }

    validateProperty = ({ name, value }) => {
        const obj = { [name]: value }
        const schema = {
            [name]: this.schema[name]
        }
        const schemaJoi = Joi.object(schema)
        const { error } = schemaJoi.validate(obj)
        return error ? error.details[0].message : null
    }

    handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault()

        const errors = this.validate()
        console.log(errors)
        this.setState({ errors: errors || {} })
        if (errors) return

        this.doSubmit()
    }

    handleChange = ({ currentTarget: input }) => {
        const errors = { ...this.state.errors }
        const errorMessage = this.validateProperty(input)
        if (errorMessage) errors[input.name] = errorMessage
        else delete errors[input.name]

        const data = { ...this.state.data }
        data[input.name] = input.value
        this.setState({ data, errors })
    }

    renderButton = label => {
        return (
            <button disabled={this.validate()} className="btn btn-primary">
                {label}
            </button>
        )
    }

    renderInput = (name, label, type = "text") => {
        const { data, errors } = this.state
        return (
            <Input
                name={name}
                label={label}
                error={errors[name]}
                type={type}
                value={data[name]}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
        )
    }
}

export default Form
```

loginForm.jsx [Class Component which extends the other]

```
import Joi from "joi"
import Form from "./common/form"

class LoginForm extends Form {
    state = {
        data: { username: "", password: "" },
        errors: {}
    }

    schema = {
        username: Joi.string().required().label("Username"),
        password: Joi.string().required().label("Password")
    }

    doSubmit = () => {
        console.log("Submitted")
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Login</h1>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    {this.renderInput("username", "Username")}
                    {this.renderInput("password", "Password", "password")}
                    {this.renderButton("Login")}
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default LoginForm
```

I already know how to convert a simple Class Component to a Stateless Functional Component but what I don't know is how to convert a Class Component which extends another Class Component.

Please, may you explain me how?

Comment: I think this is a duplicated question, can you check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59487504/how-to-rewrite-a-react-class-that-extends-another-class-as-a-functional-componen

Comment: @joseglego thanks. It could be but I didn't understand how it works in my specific case.